# Sorting keys an values

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, dictionary, plist

I am having difficultys sorting keys from a propertylist in IOS.

I am loading the list in to a dictionary an from that I extract the keys to an array sorting them with the metode: "sortedArrayUsingSelector'selector(compare:)"

When I try to use the keys, the values seems not to have been sorted along apending to there keys?
Exsample: (keys vallues)
Unsorted: Assens 0, Odense 1, Nyborg 1, Middelfart 0.
Sorted: Assens, 1, Odense 1, Nyborg 0, Middelfart 0.

`

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *KSplistURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"KommunerStedtillæg" 
                               withExtension:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary 
                                dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:KSplistURL];
    self.kommuner = dictionary;

    //NSArray *keys = [[self.kommuner allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare)];

    NSArray *components = [self.kommuner allKeys];
    NSArray *keys = [components sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];


    NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (id key in keys)[newDict setObject:[dictionary objectForKey:key]forKey:key];




    self.kommunerKeys = [newDict allKeys];
    self.kommunerValues = [newDict allValues];
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think the dictionary would know about the fact that you're sorting an unrelated copy of its key array? You have to create another dictionary like this:

```
NSArray *keys = [[originalDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (id key in keys)
    [newDict setObject:[originalDict objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
```

Now `newDict` contains the sorted keys *and* values.

Comment: Thanks but now the app crashed...
Can you explain this line for me?
for (id key in keys)
        [newDict setObject:[dictionary objectForKey:key]forKey:key];

Comment: If it's not obvious, you should really not be developing apps... It's a for loop iterating tgrough all the sorted keys adding the objects in the same order. Btw unless you post the exact error message, I can't help much.

Comment: I tryed to comment som lines out, and the problem seems to be the creation of the array *keys.

Comment: I may have typed something wrong. I just copy and pasted your code, and no errors - but the keys are not sorted.

Comment: Do you use `newDict`? This doesn't sort the keys of the original dictionary, it creates a new one instead.

Comment: NSArray *keys = [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (id key in keys)
        [newDict setObject:[dictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];    
    kommunerKeys = [newDict allKeys];
    kommunerValues = [newDict allValues];

Comment: Ok, a little sorting is happening:Sorted:  
Ærø, Svendborg, Nyborg, Langeland, Kerteminde, Nordfyn, Middelfart, Assens, Odense, Faaborg-Midtfyn


UnSorted:
Nordfyn, Svendborg, Nyborg,  Langeland, Assens, Kerteminde, Middelfart, Odense, Ærø, Faaborg-Midtfyn